# Unable to locate package mininet

Tags: virtualbox-networking

I have installed virtualbox on windows 8 and started ubuntu 14.04 version as virtual machine on virtualbox. Now, through a terminal, I used the commands `sudo apt-get install virtualbox-guest-x11` and `sudo apt-get install mininet`. Both did not work. It gave these sorts of errors:

```
E: unable to locate package mininet/virtualbox-guest-x11
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: mininet is in the `universe` repos. Is this enabled in `/etc/apt/sources.list`? Otherwise, did you perform `sudo apt-get update` before?

Comment: virtualbox-guest-x11 is in `multiverse`...

Answer (score 0):

According to your error message you did not install either mininet or virtualbox-guest-x11 but rather you tried to install a nonexistent package called mininet/virtualbox-guest-x11. The correct command to install them both from the terminal is:

```
sudo apt-get install mininet virtualbox-guest-x11
```

...or you can also install them both from the Ubuntu Software Center.